# Resharper user var where evident everywhere in file?

Tags: resharper

If you set Resharper to 'use when var when evident' it still will show this window when clicking on the suggestion in the left column.

Use 'var' everywhere in file

Use 'var' everywhere in folder

Use 'var' everywhere in project

Use 'var' everywhere in solution

I was wondering if there was a way to change this to match my preferences?

Answer (score 2):

There is the same issue in [ReSharper bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-461111)